# why datetime.now() shows invalid result when executed inside django server?

Tags: python, django, datetime

Case 1

```
>>> datetime.__file__
'/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/datetime.so'
>>> print datetime.datetime.now()
2010-05-19 19:45:40.202634
```

Case 2

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
print datetime.__file__
print "--------------------------", datetime.datetime.now()
```

-----------Result--------

```
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Validating models...
/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/datetime.so
-------------------------- 2010-05-19 09:16:43.987508
0 errors found
```

Comment: Um... looks good to me.  Can you edit your question to explain how this output fails to meet your expectations?

Comment: yes it seems its due to timezone diff. but how to solve the problem with django server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mark pointed it looks like time zone difference for Japan:

```
>>> from dateutil import tz
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> utc_time = datetime(2010, 5, 19, 9, 16, 43, tzinfo=tz.tzutc())
>>> jst_time = utc_time.astimezone(tz.gettz('Japan'))
>>> print utc_time
2010-05-19 09:16:43+00:00
>>> print jst_time
2010-05-19 18:16:43+09:00
```

Standard `datetime` module handle naive time only, you can add a support of time zones with [`dateutil`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) (especially `dateutil.tz.tzlocal()` constructor).

Comment: you're right internally django was keeping tzinfo from settings.Time_Zone, I set to Asia/Calcutta and it worked well !